# How to, in extended ASM, update an %xmmN register using a pointer to pointer memory reference

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, att

Here's essentially the gist of the struct I have:

```
struct {
    __float128 *_SSE_register_data[4];
};
```

The gist of the extended ASM I'm having trouble with:

```
// push SSE register data onto stack
"lea -16(%%rsp), %%rsp;\r\n\t"
"movdqu %%xmm0, (%%rsp);\r\n\t"

// move in new SSE register data
// using rbx as a temporary register to get the pointer to pointer
"movq 8(%%rax), %%rbx;\r\n\t"
"movdqu (%%rbx), %%xmm0;\r\n\t"

// some more asm
// .....

// restore changed SSE register data from the stack
"lea 16(%%rsp), %%rsp;\r\n\t"
"movdqu (%%rsp), %%xmm0;\r\n\t"
```

So my problem, is with the section "move in new SSE register data", as I get a Segmentation fault when that section is included in my ASM, and not when it is not included.

So I've narrowed my issue down, but I'm not at all good at ASM, and need guidance. Is the surrounding ASM code written correctly for it's purpose? And, what changes do I need to make in the middle ASM section in order to achieve my goal of loading new data, from a pointer to pointer data value?

Hopefully the question isn't too confusing, feel free to modify it for clarity. I would really like to figure this out tonight.

Comment: Your "restore" section is wrong - it should be the reverse of the "push" order.  You need to restore `XMM0` first, then restore `ESP`.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you!